# Pandas - Calculate Relative time from csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge csv file which contains

```
highest_layer,transport_layer,src_ip,dst_ip,src_port,dst_port,ip_flag,packet_length,transport_flag,time,timestamp,geo_country,data
LAN_DISCOVERY,UDP,192.168.1.6,224.0.0.251,5353,5353,0,82,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.479232,1591832288479,Unknown,
LAN_DISCOVERY,UDP,fe80::868:621b:c2ff:cee2,ff02::fb,5353,5353,-1,102,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.479261,1591832288479,Unknown,
LAN_DISCOVERY,UDP,192.168.1.3,192.168.1.6,5353,5353,16384,409,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.506399,1591832288506,Unknown,
DNS,UDP,192.168.1.6,192.168.1.1,32631,53,0,89,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.863846,1591832288863,Unknown,
DNS,UDP,192.168.1.6,192.168.1.1,31708,53,0,79,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.864186,1591832288864,Unknown,
DNS,UDP,192.168.1.6,192.168.1.1,16807,53,0,79,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.866492,1591832288866,Unknown,
SSDP,UDP,192.168.1.6,239.255.255.250,58185,1900,0,216,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.887298,1591832288887,Unknown,
DNS,UDP,192.168.1.1,192.168.1.6,53,32631,16384,105,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.888232,1591832288888,Unknown,
TCP,TCP,192.168.1.6,172.217.12.131,53717,443,16384,78,2,2020-06-10 19:38:08.888553,1591832288888,Unknown,
DNS,UDP,192.168.1.1,192.168.1.6,53,31708,16384,95,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.895148,1591832288895,Unknown,
TCP,TCP,192.168.1.6,172.217.10.237,53718,443,16384,78,2,2020-06-10 19:38:08.895594,1591832288895,Unknown,
DNS,UDP,192.168.1.1,192.168.1.6,53,16807,16384,119,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.896202,1591832288896,Unknown,
TCP,TCP,192.168.1.6,172.217.11.14,53719,443,16384,78,2,2020-06-10 19:38:08.896540,1591832288896,Unknown,
DNS,UDP,192.168.1.6,192.168.1.1,20557,53,0,75,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.911968,1591832288911,Unknown,
DATA,UDP,192.168.1.3,192.168.1.6,51216,58185,16384,558,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.913276,1591832288913,Unknown,
TCP,TCP,172.217.12.131,192.168.1.6,443,53717,0,74,18,2020-06-10 19:38:08.916735,1591832288916,Unknown,
TCP,TCP,192.168.1.6,172.217.12.131,53717,443,16384,66,16,2020-06-10 19:38:08.916860,1591832288916,Unknown,
TLS,TCP,192.168.1.6,172.217.12.131,53717,443,16384,583,24,2020-06-10 19:38:08.917442,1591832288917,Unknown,
TCP,TCP,172.217.10.237,192.168.1.6,443,53718,0,74,18,2020-06-10 19:38:08.919293,1591832288919,Unknown,
TCP,TCP,192.168.1.6,172.217.10.237,53718,443,16384,66,16,2020-06-10 19:38:08.919423,1591832288919,Unknown,
TLS,TCP,192.168.1.6,172.217.10.237,53718,443,16384,583,24,2020-06-10 19:38:08.919593,1591832288919,Unknown,
TCP,TCP,172.217.11.14,192.168.1.6,443,53719,0,74,18,2020-06-10 19:38:08.928819,1591832288928,Unknown,
TCP,TCP,192.168.1.6,172.217.11.14,53719,443,16384,66,16,2020-06-10 19:38:08.928922,1591832288928,Unknown,
TLS,TCP,192.168.1.6,172.217.11.14,53719,443,16384,583,24,2020-06-10 19:38:08.929100,1591832288929,Unknown,
DNS,UDP,192.168.1.1,192.168.1.6,53,20557,16384,317,-1,2020-06-10 19:38:08.932758,1591832288932,Unknown,
TCP,TCP,192.168.1.6,172.217.12.174,53720,443,16384,78,2,2020-06-10 19:38:08.933034,1591832288933,Unknown,
TCP,TCP,172.217.12.131,192.168.1.6,443,53717,0,66,16,2020-06-10 19:38:08.947137,1591832288947,Unknown,
TCP,TCP,172.217.10.237,192.168.1.6,443,53718,0,66,16,2020-06-10 19:38:08.952060,1591832288952,Unknown,
TLS,TCP,172.217.12.131,192.168.1.6,443,53717,0,1484,16,2020-06-10 19:38:08.954404,1591832288954,Unknown,
```

I want to **find the relative time for the timestamp and plot it against the cumulative packet length**.Here is what i tried.

```
datadis = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=',')
dfd = (datadis[(datadis.src_port == 53725)])
dfd1 = dfd.drop(columns=['highest_layer', 'transport_layer','ip_flag', 'transport_flag','geo_country','data'])
dfd1.to_csv('disabletry.txt',index=False)
dfd1.index = dfd1['timestamp'] - dfd1.loc[0,'timestamp']
dfd2 = dfd1.groupby(['src_ip'])['packet_length'].cumsum()
#dfd2.to_csv('disableplot.txt',index=False)
dfd2.plot(x='time',y=['packet_length'])
```

I get the following error.

```
---> 14 dfd1.index = dfd1['timestamp'] - dfd1.loc[0,'timestamp']
 # we by definition only have the 0th axis
 # we have yielded a scalar ?
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item() 
pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()
KeyError: 0
```

Comment: I can ran your code successfully. In your first snippet, it is `dfd` while it is `dfd1` in your error log. Do you have any other operation?

Comment: In my environment (Python:3.6.2,pandas:1.0.5), there are no errors It was.

Comment: I just renamed the variables to make it easier to read. Let me edit the original code and see what goes wrong

Comment: This may be the cause of the error. Make sure the index of the data extracted by 'src_port' is '0'.

Comment: I tried writing the datas after extracting the src_port into a file and the index starts with 0.

Comment: Does 'src_port == 53725' exist in the sample data presented?

Comment: No. Its a huge file.I just gave a snippet of it.But the port is present in the file i read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If `dfd = (datadis[(datadis.src_port == 53725)])` results in an empty dataframe, the error happens.
- Add [`dfd.empty`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.empty.html) and if `True` skip the remainder.
- Also, you must `.reset_index()` when creating `dfd1`, otherwise there may be no `.loc[0,'timestamp']`

```py
datadis = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep=',')
dfd = (datadis[(datadis.src_port == 53725)])
if not dfd.empty:  # only proceed if the dataframe is not empty
    dfd1 = dfd.drop(columns=['highest_layer', 'transport_layer','ip_flag', 'transport_flag','geo_country','data']).reset_index()
    dfd1.to_csv('disabletry.txt',index=False)
    dfd1.index = dfd1['timestamp'] - dfd1.loc[0,'timestamp']
    dfd2 = dfd1.groupby(['src_ip'])['packet_length'].cumsum()
    #dfd2.to_csv('disableplot.txt',index=False)
    dfd2.plot(x='time',y=['packet_length'])
```

- Given your sample data

```py
for i, g in datadis.groupby('src_port'):
    g = pd.DataFrame(g)
    if not g.empty:
        dfd1 = g.drop(columns=['highest_layer', 'transport_layer','ip_flag', 'transport_flag','geo_country','data']).reset_index(drop=True)
        new_index = dfd1['timestamp'] - dfd1.loc[0,'timestamp']
        dfd1.index = new_index
        dfd2 = dfd1.groupby(['src_ip'])['packet_length'].cumsum()
        dfd2.plot(x='time', y=['packet_length'], label=i)
plt.legend(title='src_port')
```

- In this small data example, if there is only 1 timestamp for a group, then there's not packet length.

[image]

### Plot `cumsum` vs. `timestamp`

- Previous plot was against `dfd1['timestamp'] - dfd1.loc[0,'timestamp']`, whereas this plots just `dfd1['timestamp']` as the index.

```py
for i, g in datadis.groupby('src_port'):
    g = pd.DataFrame(g)
    if not g.empty:
        dfd1 = g.drop(columns=['highest_layer', 'transport_layer','ip_flag', 'transport_flag','geo_country','data']).reset_index(drop=True)
        dfd1.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
        display(dfd1)  # display is for jupyter notebook. Change to print if not in a notebook
        dfd2 = dfd1.groupby(['src_ip'])['packet_length'].cumsum()
        display(dfd2)  # display is for jupyter notebook. Change to print if not in a notebook
        print('\n')
        if len(dfd2) < 2:
            print(f'src_port: {i} only has 1 timestamp so nothing will be plotted.\n')
        else:
            plt.figure()
            dfd2.plot(x='time', y=['packet_length'], label=i)
            plt.legend(title='src_port')
            plt.show()
```

Comment: Wow. Worked like breeze. Thanks